# how to get return value from javascript to .cs page

Tags: c#, javascript

```
// JScript File
function fnCheckBrowserType(var k)
{
if(k>0)
{
document.getElementByID('<%=HhdnBrowsertype.ClientID%>').value="1"
return true;
}
else
{
document.getElementByID('<%=HhdnBrowsertype.ClientID%>').value="0"
return false;
}
```

**in.cs page  load**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "fnCheckBrowserType", "fnCheckBrowserType();", true);
```

here i need  to gets  its  return vale  based on the  return value  "true " or "false"
i need  to check the  condition

pls  help me  to get the  value  from javascript  to  .cs  page

thanks 
prince

Comment: How do you expect to get the return value of a javascript function in the code behind assuming that this javascript function runs on the client much later and after the server side code has already finished executing. At the time this javascript runs there is no longer code behind. Your best bet is to send this value in a subsequent HTTP request to the server. This could be done either using AJAX or including the result in a hidden field for example.

Answer (score 0):

To send data to the server from the client, you have some options:

- Send in a form.
- Use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).
- Indirectly request a resource from the server and use a query string to send the information (for instance, adding an `img` element which uses a query string in its `src`). Not recommended, but possible and perhaps useful in some edge cases (for instance, when you need to send the data cross-origin and need to avoid the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), as with many ad serving scripts).
- Have the data piggy-back on your next normal request by setting a cookie.

Given the scenario you describe, Ajax may be your best option.